# Scala RegEx String extractors behaving inconsistently

Tags: java, regex, string, scala, pattern-matching

I have two regular expression extractors.

One for .java files and the other is for .scala files

```
val JavaFileRegEx =
  """\S*
     \s+
     //
     \s{1}
     ([^\.java]+)
     \.java
  """.replaceAll("(\\s)", "").r

val ScalaFileRegEx =
  """\S*
     \s+
     //
     \s{1}
     ([^\.scala]+)
     \.scala
  """.replaceAll("(\\s)", "").r
```

I want to use these extractors above to extract a java file name and a scala file name from the example code below.

```
val string1 = " // Tester.java"
val string2 = " // Hello.scala"

string1 match {
  case JavaFileRegEx(fileName1) => println(" Java file: " + fileName1)
  case other => println(other + "--NO_MATCH")
}
string2 match {
  case ScalaFileRegEx(fileName2) => println(" Scala file: " + fileName2)
  case other => println(other + "--NO_MATCH")
}
```

I get this output indicating that the .java file matched but the .scala file did not.

```
 Java file: Tester
 // Hello.scala--NO_MATCH
```

How is it that the Java file matched but the .scala file did not?

Comment: your use of character class is wrong in `[^\.scala]` and `[^\.java]` both

Comment: @rock321987 - I'm confused by the "^" character. I thought `[^\.java]` meant "match everything up until .java"

Comment: it means don't match any **character** in this set: `/\|/.|s|c|a|l|a`. hello contains an 'l', thus it is not matched. I recommend you just use `\w` instead of the character classes. If '.' could be part of a filename, then use `[\w.]`. The rest of the regex (`/.scala`) still needs to match. You could also use `?` just to be sure.

Comment: for example: `\S*\s+//\\s{1}([\w.]+)\.java`.

Comment: Does Scala not support the `(?x)` modifier?  I know Java does.  Put `(?x)` as the first thing in the regex, and you shouldn't have to bother with that `.replaceAll("(\\s)", "")` step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***NOTE***

> `[]` denotes character class. It matches only a single character.
>
> `[^]`  denotes match anything **except** the ***characters*** present in the character class.

In your first regex

```
\S*\s+//\s{1}([^\.java]+)\.java
```

> `\S*` matches nothing as there is space in starting
>
> `\s+` matches the space which is in starting
>
> `//` matches `//` literally
>
> `\s{1}` matches next space

You are using `[^\.java]` which says **match anything except** `.` or `j` or `a` or `v` or `a` which can be written as `[^.jav]`.

So, the left string now to be tested is

```
Tester.java
```

(Un)luckily any character from `Tester` does not matches `.` or `j` or `a` or `v` until we encounter a `.`. So `Tester` is matched and then `java` is also matched.

In your second regex

```
\S*\s+//\s{1}([^\.scala]+)\.scala
```

> `\S*` matches  nothing as there is space in starting
>
> `\s+` matches the space which is in starting
>
> `//` matches `//` literally
>
> `\s{1}` matches next space

Now, you are using `[^\.scala]` which says that **match anything except** `.` or `s` or `c` or `a` or `l` or `a` which can be written as `[^.scla]`.

You have now

```
Hello.scala
```

but (un)luckily `Hello` here contains `l` which is not allowed according to character class and the regex fails.

**How to correct it?**

I will modify only a bit of your regex

```
\S*\s+//\s{1}([^.]*)\.java
              <-->
   This says that match anything except .
   You can also use \w here instead if [^.]
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/kK8pH9/2)**

```
\S*\s+//\s{1}([^.]*)\.scala
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/kK8pH9/1)**

There is no need of `{1}` in `\s{1}`. You can simply write it as `\s` and it will match exactly one space like

```
\S*\s+//\s([^.]*)\.java
```